# auto scale webpage to fit mobile screen

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Lets say I've prepared one mobile version for all smartphones and I've chosen 320px for my banner - background image (320x177), the code looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    body {margin: auto; max-width:320px}
    #banner {height: 177px; max-width: 100%; background-position: center top; background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-size: contain;}
    #banner {background-image: url("background320.jpg"); border:1px solid black;}
    #banner span {margin:15% 0 0 10%}   
    #content {max-width: 100%; height: 1000px; border:1px solid black;}
}

<div id="banner">
   <span>Banner Title</span>
</div>
<div id="content"> Some content </div>
```

In this case if the screen is larger (like my phone 360px wide portrait), I get white stripes on the left and right side. I don't want make another mobile version for 360px, but I just want scale up the page to fit the screen (the same as you do manually with two fingers). If the screen is smaller then would scale down to fit the window. How to do it? OR how should it be this done properly referring to this example?

**EDIT:** I tried to use `background-size: 100% 100%` to keep background aspect ratio when showing on different screen resolution, but there is always problem with height. If I don't set up static height `height:177px` then the background height is only as high as the content inside or doesn't appear at all if there is no content inside it. The static height is also bad when it must be shown on a different screen resolutions. How do you solve this without making additional mobile versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `background-size:cover` or `background-size:100%`, instead of `background-size:contain`.

**Edit:** Sounds like you want the div to keep the aspect ratio of the image. If so, you can use zero height on the div with vertical padding:

```css
#banner {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/320x177);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding-top: 55.3125%;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Comment: @soonic Are you trying to keep the aspect ratio of the div equal on all screens? Check updated answer

Comment: well, there is a problem when I have things inside the `<div id="banner"></div>`, it makes a mess when I use zero height and this padding. It keeps the right aspect ratio of the image, but the content of the div doesn't look good. Actually, I was asking if it's possible to auto scale in/out the entire page to fit the window (like with the two fingers zoom in/out)?

Comment: I've updated my post question. Probably your answer would be good if I didn't have content inside the banner div, but if I do then it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @soonic You can use an overlay div with `position:absolute`.

Comment: @soonic Or you can try setting fixed width in the viewport tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">`

Comment: ok, I got it work as I needed with the rest of my content. The banner div should be `position: relative` where the span should be in `position: absolute` so then I can work with it. I use your solution so the answer is accepted. Just add that this number for `padding-top` is the height/width*100.

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap .no need to make different layout for different sizes,it's a pre-made css for fluid layout.so use the classes of it.here is link for bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ download the bootstrap css link it in html and use class "col-md-6" for both the divs.they become responsive to screen size.